# Replace string in a lot of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have write a script for renaming it is like this

```
for i in *.xml
do
    cp ${i} "suffix${i:6}"
done
```

but I do not know how to change the text inside the xml file.

For example in all the files I have the word "asdfg" and I want to replace that with "qwert".

I know is possible and probably simple to do it in bash script but I do not know how to code this and I do not know even how to google it

Thanks

Comment: If the file is properly structured XML, there are special dedicated tools for that, like `xsltproc`. With that, you can subsistute, say, only in tag names, or only between tags, or in a specific set of XML sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in *.xml ; do
    sed -e 's/asdfg/qwert/g' <"$i" >"suffix${i:6}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A google for "replace string in files" gave me the following link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

... which gives one solution using `sed` and a `bash` loop (like in your original example.)